# How to select items with all possible id-s or just a particular one using the same query?

Tags: sql

Is there a variable in SQL that can be used to represent **ALL** the possible values of a field? Something like this pseudo-code

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = *ALL_EXISTING_ID-s*
```

I want to return all rows in this case, but later when I do a search and need only one item I can simply replace that variable with the `id` I'm looking for, i.e.

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: Do you mean some sort of really long OR statement, or just all values in a table?

Comment: Why don't you go with 2 different queries?

Comment: @arxanas it's a really long statement with a lot of fields to select from and conditions

Comment: @NAnocom I could. Just wanted to know if it's possible to do it in one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to remove the WHERE clause. This will return all rows.

```
SELECT name FROM table
```

If you want some "magic" value you can use for the ID that you can use in your existing query and it will return all rows, I think you're out of luck.

Though you could use something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = IFNULL(?, id)
```

If the value `NULL` is provided, all rows will be returned.

If you don't like `NULL` then try the following query, which will return all rows if the value `-1` is provided:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = IFNULL(NULLIF(?, -1), id)
```

Another approach that achieves the same effect (but requires binding the id twice) is:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE (id = ? OR ? = -1)
```

Comment: I need to use the `WHERE` - it's just a very simplified example. The real one includes a lot of joins, fields to compare against and conditions. But the latters seem to be a solution